# Fixed effects model using Python linearmodels

Tags: python, regression, linearmodels

I am a little confused by the requirement for a MultiIndex using linearmodels PanelOLS. I'm trying to create a model of the form
y = pid(i) + rid(j) + e(ij)
where e is the error term.
My data essentially looks like this:
[Dataframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rStZf.png)

In this case I basically want to end up with 6 coefficients: p1,p2,p3,r1,r2,r3

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['pid'] = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
df['rid'] = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
df['y'] = [100,102,101,98,96,101,101,100,103]
```

Trying to use this:

```
from linearmodels.panel import PanelOLS
mod = PanelOLS(df.y, df[['pid','rid']], entity_effects=True)
res = mod.fit(cov_type='clustered', cluster_entity=True)
```

This gives an error, saying I need a 2-level MultiIndex. I'm unsure what this should consist of, so help would be much appreciated!

I've tried the approach of changing it to normal linear regression by cross-tabbing the array to have the 6 fields and having 1s and 0s in the values, but this falls over for my actual dataset as it has around 5000 p values and 1000 r values.

Comment: I am having similar confusion, however, I guess you can try: mod = PanelOLS(df.y, df['rid'], entity_effects=True) and then df['pid'] not sure if that correct or not, I am brainstorming here.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Daniel you just have to create the appropiate multi-index by adding the following lines to your code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['pid'] = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
df['rid'] = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
df['y'] = [100,102,101,98,96,101,101,100,103]

df['individual'] = ['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c']
df['time'] = [10,11,12,10,11,12,10,11,12]
df = df.set_index(['individual','time'])


from linearmodels.panel import PanelOLS
mod = PanelOLS(df.y, df[['pid','rid']], entity_effects=False)
res = mod.fit(cov_type='clustered', cluster_entity=True)
print(res.params)

pid    22.756410
rid    23.589744
Name: parameter, dtype: float64
```

This is because the variables of a panel have multi-index X_it to identify it.